# How do I retreive partial HTML from a URL in Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I'm trying my hand at web scraping, and everything's working except I'm using it on blogs with Disqus comments that take around 30 seconds to load. I don't need the Disqus comments, just the content of the blog, which loads almost immediately. How do I get only what I need so there's no excessive waiting?

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url) # This takes too long because of Disqus

# Web scraping stuff here
```

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: This could also be useful https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/is-it-possible-to-stop-page-loading-on-the-browser-using-selenium-web-driver

Comment: Yep, the answer to the possible duplicate question did the trick. Just needed to change the code for Firefox instead of Chrome. Thank you!